# Dashboard RSS Widget Overhaul

Tags: admin, dashboard

I want to give add an order digit on to the dashboard feed like in the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK0GJ.png

I edited default-widgets.php - function wp_widget_rss_output () but it's still not showing any changes.

PS: I'm using WPMUDEV Dashboard Feeds plugin. This plugin changes the widget_options so that I can show my own RSS feed and not the default Wordpress ones!

Answer (score 1):

> I edited default-widgets.php - function wp_widget_rss_output () but
> it's still not showing any changes.

There is

## NO NEED TO MODIFY CORE FILES!!!!

Especially with dashboard widgets where a [very extensible API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API) as been provided by WordPress.

> PS: I'm using WPMUDEV Dashboard Feeds plugin. This plugin changes the
> widget_options so that I can show my own RSS feed and not the default
> Wordpress ones!

You should try getting support for your commercial plugin over at the [WPMUDEV forums](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/search.php?q=Dashboard%20Feeds)